# Show that functional dependency pseudotransivity holds using closure test

Tags: relational-theory, dependencies

I'm currently studying a basic database course with the course literature [*Database Systems - The Complete Book*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873253)<sup>1</sup>.

In one of the book's exercises you are asked to

> Show that the following rules hold, by using the closure test.

This is the closure test described in the book:

> [image: Closure test part 1]
>   [image: Closure test part 2]

And the question I'm having trouble with is as follows:

> [image: Exercise 3.2.4 c)]

How can I show that the rules hold? Can I do it by computing the closures of the relevant attributes somehow prove that?

Thank you in advance!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Garcia-Molina, H. & Ullman, J. D. & Widom, J. (2009). [*Database Systems - The Complete Book*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873253), Second Edition. Pearson Education Inc., Upper Saddle River, NJ, USA.</sup>

Comment: That might get better attention at [cs.se] or [cstheory.se]

Answer (score 2):

The definition of Pseudotransitivity given above is equivalent to say the following.

From:

```
(1) A1 A2 ... An -> B1 B2 ... Bm
(2) B1 B2 ... Bm E1 E2 ... Ej -> D
```

we can derive:

```
(3) A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej -> D
```

Here is a possible simple proof.

Let’s try to compute the closure of `{A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej}` from the first two functional dependencies. If this closure contains `D` then we have proved the hypothesis.

```
{A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej}+ = A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej    (starting point)
{A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej}+ = A1 A2 ... An B1 B2 ... Bm E1 E2 ... Ej (by using 1)
{A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej}+ = A1 A2 ... An B1 B2 ... Bm D E1 E2 ... Ej (by using 2)
No other derivation is possible.
```

So, since `D` is included in the closure of `{A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej}`, we have shown that `A1 A2 ... An E1 E2 ... Ej -> D`.